# Common Response to A Ref's Bad Call

Tags: word, rebus

A Common Response to A Ref's Bad Call

[image: RefBadCallRebus]

Comment: mreb hcibgrf. bx, V urne ln, ab zber "fvzcyr erohfrf jvgu pbzcyrk jbeqf gung zbfg crbcyr unir gb ybbx hc"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't know this was a word myself (before I looked it up), but it sure looks like

> C on TR over T in G

to me.